# Is there any way I could sue ezpass?

Tags: united-states, traffic, massachusetts

Is there any way I could sue ezpass? For no reason ez pass MA did not charge my credit card claiming it does not work and send me invoice plus late fees!

Comment: Are you asking how you file a suit against the state? Or are you asking whether it would be pointless to do so because they didn't act illegally?

Comment: They charged the same credit card next month. There was no issue with my credit card. I asked them to charge my credit card again but they did not. I called them again and asked them to charge my card again they did not and so on..... no the fee got $280 while the real charge is $26.30. For some unknown reason to me they did not want to charge my card for $26.30 while card was fine.

Comment: So what is your question? I understand the facts as you represent them, I don't understand whether you're asking advice about how to frame the lawsuit, or whether the lawsuit would be a waste of your time, or simply what court you go to.

Comment: They do not want to charge my credit card. Everytime I call them and ask them why they don't charge my credit card in the file they say ok and don't do and add more fees. I wanted to take them to small claim court... But the court wants person in charge... but no one is in charge for ezpass....they have board which governor is the chair. So who should I write as defendant?

Answer (score 3):

You can absolutely sue the entity that operates EZpass because it is a private company and you have a monetary dispute with it (unless the agreement you entered into with EZpass to allow it to charge your credit card contains an arbitration clause). But, this would make no sense.

Everybody agrees that you owe EZpass money for tolls that you admit that you incurred, and if you don't pay that you are clearly in the wrong. The fact that they weren't able to charge your credit card for some reason (who knows, maybe there's a typo in your records or the phone line had static at a critical moment when they tried to process the charge, it doesn't really matter why), doesn't mean that you don't owe them money for the tolls that you incurred and if the sue you at a time when you still owe money for that toll you will definitely lose.

The only dispute is over the late fee. And, the dispute is that you have to pay something that you haven't actually paid. So, in the status quo, in which you haven't paid a late fee which you believe you don't owe, and you are winning for now.

Generally speaking, one brings a lawsuit to change the status quo. EZpass is the party that claims you owe money and hasn't been paid, so ordinarily EZpass would sue you and not the other way around, because it wants to change the status quo.

Now, realistically, bringing a lawsuit for a single late fee is insane. The filing fee alone is more than the late fee, you couldn't afford to hire a lawyer for twelve minutes without paying more than the cost of the late fee, and the contract with EZpass very likely doesn't allow you to get your attorneys' fees if you prevail.

The bigger question, which might make a lawsuit worthwhile, is that if you don't pay your late fee, EZpass could ban you from using toll roads entirely and impose big fines that are authorized by your agreement with you if you do.

In short, if you can't work it out with customer service reps and their managers at EZpass over the phone, you would be a complete fool to sue rather than to pay the late fee that you think was wrongly imposed. Not every battle, even when you are in the right, is worth fighting.

Comment: I would like to pay the fee and have no objection but not late fees since it is because of them not my end. They don't have manager or supervisor and looks like who gets up early morning is manager.

Comment: @joe I understand what you want to do. What I am telling you is that it doesn't appear that you can do what you want to do. Therefore, you need to break the Gordian knot and pay it all underprotest and seek a return of the excess amount due with or without litigation.

Comment: "if the sue you at a time when you still owe money for that toll you will definitely lose." That is utterly false. It is quite possible to win a judgment against a party while still owing money to that party.

Comment: @Acccumulation They countersue for the money you owe and the net judgment is against you and you end up paying court costs and quite possibly legal fees.

Comment: There are three main possible outcomes: (1) The court finds that the OP has made the money available to them and by failing to claim it, they have forfeited it. (2) The court finds that the debt is still valid, but EZpass has not given the OP an opportunity to pay it, and therefore suing is inappropriate (3) The court finds that suing is appropriate. You cannot say that the OP will "definitely" lose. The courts don't look kindly on parties refusing to accept payment for a debt and then suing to recover that debt, and such behavior could very well lead to sanctions.

Comment: "The courts don't look kindly on parties refusing to accept payment for a debt and then suing to recover that debt, and such behavior could very well lead to sanctions." I've never seen a court have a problem with it, let alone sanction a party for it. Courts are surprising blaise about that sort of thing.

Answer (score -2):

EZ pass is designed to work exactly as Ohwilleke described. Ez pass can and does steal money from its customers, but the amounts are small and EZ pass is a huge.

As an individual, not only would suing make no financial sense, but it would be financial disaster for almost anyone who tries. Any lawyer would explain this to a victim/ client the same way Ohwilleke did above.

So what can you do besides pay hundreds each year? Well, if you are truly motivated, to me there only seems to be one option - crowdsource. There are hundreds of thousands of extremely upset folks out there, who arguably, would be pumped to donate $$ to pay for a case like this. It would take a of work and strategic thinking to make happen, but could be done and would be admirable.